# uninitialized constant Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm trying to use the Selenium Webdriver gem to write a test but am getting the following error. 
"test.rb:4:in `': uninitialized constant Selenium (NameError)"

I can't seem to figure out why its giving me this error. I have pasted the code for the test below.

```
"require rubygems"
"require selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

that is where it fails. The rest of the test is pretty page-specific js executions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your requires do nothing, you just wrote unused String literals, change it to:

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"
```

Comment: Thanks, Feelin pretty dumb.

Comment: Don't worry about it, in my experience the stupider the error is, the harder it is to spot :)